# Azure Databricks Sentiment Analysis

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

I was following this tutorial regarding Databricks. In te final section, when calling the Language and Sentiment API, the sentiment column always return "Couldn't Detect Language". I'm not familiar enough with Scala to solve this problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/databricks-sentiment-analysis-cognitive-services

This is the piece of code i'm running (The same as the tutorial):

```
import java.io._
import java.net._
import java.util._

case class Language(documents: Array[LanguageDocuments], errors: Array[Any]) extends Serializable
case class LanguageDocuments(id: String, detectedLanguages: Array[DetectedLanguages]) extends Serializable
case class DetectedLanguages(name: String, iso6391Name: String, score: Double) extends Serializable

case class Sentiment(documents: Array[SentimentDocuments], errors: Array[Any]) extends Serializable
case class SentimentDocuments(id: String, score: Double) extends Serializable

case class RequestToTextApi(documents: Array[RequestToTextApiDocument]) extends Serializable
case class RequestToTextApiDocument(id: String, text: String, var language: String = "") extends Serializable

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
import scala.util.parsing.json._

object SentimentDetector extends Serializable {

    // Cognitive Services API connection settings
    val accessKey = "<PROVIDE ACCESS KEY HERE>"
    val host = "https://cognitive-docs.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
    val languagesPath = "/text/analytics/v2.1/languages"
    val sentimentPath = "/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment"
    val languagesUrl = new URL(host+languagesPath)
    val sentimenUrl = new URL(host+sentimentPath)
    val g = new Gson

    def getConnection(path: URL): HttpsURLConnection = {
        val connection = path.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpsURLConnection]
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/json")
        connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", accessKey)
        connection.setDoOutput(true)
        return connection
    }

    def prettify (json_text: String): String = {
        val parser = new JsonParser()
        val json = parser.parse(json_text).getAsJsonObject()
        val gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
        return gson.toJson(json)
    }

    // Handles the call to Cognitive Services API.
    def processUsingApi(request: RequestToTextApi, path: URL): String = {
        val requestToJson = g.toJson(request)
        val encoded_text = requestToJson.getBytes("UTF-8")
        val connection = getConnection(path)
        val wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())
        wr.write(encoded_text, 0, encoded_text.length)
        wr.flush()
        wr.close()

        val response = new StringBuilder()
        val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))
        var line = in.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            response.append(line)
            line = in.readLine()
        }
        in.close()
        return response.toString()
    }

    // Calls the language API for specified documents.
    def getLanguage (inputDocs: RequestToTextApi): Option[Language] = {
        try {
            val response = processUsingApi(inputDocs, languagesUrl)
            // In case we need to log the json response somewhere
            val niceResponse = prettify(response)
            // Deserializing the JSON response from the API into Scala types
            val language = g.fromJson(niceResponse, classOf[Language])
            if (language.documents(0).detectedLanguages(0).iso6391Name == "(Unknown)")
                return None
            return Some(language)
        } catch {
            case e: Exception => return None
        }
    }

    // Calls the sentiment API for specified documents. Needs a language field to be set for each of them.
    def getSentiment (inputDocs: RequestToTextApi): Option[Sentiment] = {
        try {
            val response = processUsingApi(inputDocs, sentimenUrl)
            val niceResponse = prettify(response)
            // Deserializing the JSON response from the API into Scala types
            val sentiment = g.fromJson(niceResponse, classOf[Sentiment])
            return Some(sentiment)
        } catch {
            case e: Exception => return None
        }
    }
}

// User Defined Function for processing content of messages to return their sentiment.
val toSentiment =
    udf((textContent: String) =>
        {
            val inputObject = new RequestToTextApi(Array(new RequestToTextApiDocument(textContent, textContent)))
            val detectedLanguage = SentimentDetector.getLanguage(inputObject)
            detectedLanguage match {
                case Some(language) =>
                    if(language.documents.size > 0) {
                        inputObject.documents(0).language = language.documents(0).detectedLanguages(0).iso6391Name
                        val sentimentDetected = SentimentDetector.getSentiment(inputObject)
                        sentimentDetected match {
                            case Some(sentiment) => {
                                if(sentiment.documents.size > 0) {
                                    sentiment.documents(0).score.toString()
                                }
                                else {
                                    "Error happened when getting sentiment: " + sentiment.errors(0).toString
                                }
                            }
                            case None => "Couldn't detect sentiment"
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        "Error happened when getting language" + language.errors(0).toString
                    }
                case None => "Couldn't detect language"
            }
        }
    )


// Prepare a dataframe with Content and Sentiment columns
val streamingDataFrame = incomingStream.selectExpr("cast (body as string) AS Content").withColumn("Sentiment", toSentiment($"Content"))

// Display the streaming data with the sentiment
streamingDataFrame.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```

Any thoughts?

Edited, 15/03/2022

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly-formatted text, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) explains why this is important. Beyond that, you should also show relevant code. Otherwise, someone has to visit that doc page, learn about the example, run it, and try recreating what you've done and what you're running into.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, error found. I was missing a character in the Cognitive Service's Endpoint.